# vertical and horizontal center on mobile only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, center

I would like to center a column in mobile only where I have a fixed height for my section.

```
<div class="" style="background-image: url(image url;); background-position: right bottom; background-size: cover; height: 462px;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="d-md-block d-none col-md-5" style=""><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="image url"></div>
    <div class="col-12 my-auto col-md-7">
      <h1 class="display-4">Display 4</h1><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Would you want to explore FlexBox? It's really handy for centering items, both horizontally or vertically. You'd want to enclose your code in a parent div and set

```
display:flex; 
align-items: center; //For horizontal centering
justify-content: center; //For vertical align
```

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jvknog1d/

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 462px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="" style="background-image: url(image url;); background-position: right bottom; background-size: cover; ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="d-md-block d-none col-md-5" style=""><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="image url"></div>
        <div class="col-12 my-auto col-md-7">
          <h1 class="display-4">Display 4</h1><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "@media only screen" in your CSS to change settings for different resolutions.

```css
.mysection{
background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/728x462.png?text=placeholder"); 
background-position: right bottom; 
background-size: cover; 
height: 462px;
}





@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mysection {
    text-align : center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mysection">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="d-md-block d-none col-md-5" ><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" style="border: 1px solid;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=image"></div>
    <div class="col-12 my-auto col-md-7">
      <h1 class="display-4">Display 4</h1><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more information, you can check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).